# Can I restrict the times during which iTunes downloads podcast content?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I have a capped ADSL account that splits my bandwidth allocation 50-50 between anytime and download time (midnight to 6am). I therefore prefer to have any downloading happen during download time so as not to max out my anytime bandwidth and require top-up purchase.

I subscribe to a number of podcasts in iTunes and would like to be able to restrict the downloading of those podcasts to download time. Does iTunes (on Windows) offer any way to d this?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is refresh the podcasts at a time during the download period and then set the update podcast to "Daily"

Find the settings button :-

[image: settings]

And select Daily..

[image: Podcast refresh times]

This is because the Daily refresh will reset itself to download every 24 hours after that time..

As seen here I refreshed this morning and the next update will be 24 hours after that.

[image: Refresh time]

The caveat, of course, is that iTunes must be running at the time you want it to refresh

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I'll check that tonight.